# How to convert a monthly value into a daily value?

Tags: mysql, sql

| AccountId | Date | Budget | MarketingType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 04/30/2019 | $100 | Facebook |
| 02 | 06/30/2019 | $300 | Google |

I have the following table (Marketing) that shows monthly marketing budget per 'AccountID' per 'Marketing Type' and I need to get the daily marketing spend (i.e. Budget/30) for each account and marketing type. Ignoring the fact that there are months with more/less than 30 days, how would I do this?

Note: I need to have new rows for each individual day/spend so that every monthly budget per AccountId per MarketingType has 30 rows.

Expected Answer

| AccountId | Date | Budget | MarketingType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 04/01/2019 | $3.33 | Facebook |
| 01 | 04/02/2019 | $3.33 | Facebook |
| 01 | 04/03/2019 | $3.33 | Facebook |
| 01 | 04/04/2019 | $3.33 | Facebook |
| 01 | 04/05/2019 | $3.33 | Facebook |
| 01 | 04/06/2019 | $3.33 | Facebook |
| Continued.... |  |  |  |

Comment: Budget /DAY(date)

Comment: please provide your expected result. From your question, unable to find marketing type , account type

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, 
(Budget/30) daily_spend
FROM tbl_marketing
```

If your Budget column type is FLOAT, you can proceed using this query.